# No input possible after tk

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

If have this piece of code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog

menu = tk.Tk()
res = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() # un-/comment this line
label = tk.Label(None, text="abc")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
entry = tk.Entry(None)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)

res = menu.mainloop()
```

Note: the `askopenfilename` is just a dummy input. So Just close it to get to the (now blocked) main window of TK.

When I comment the `askopenfilename` everything works fine. But with the it, I can not enter data in the entry.

This only happens with Windoze environments. The `askopenfilename` seems to steal the focus for the main TK window. After clicking a totally different window and back again in the TK window, input is possible.

Comment: As it is written in the question, the code nicely offers me to pick a file from my file explorer of the operating system with a click, but then of course this string (the path) is not used. When I replace the `text="abc"` label with `text=res` the label in the label box displays the filepath. Please add more expectations or observations to the question. As it stands it does not give me the impression, it will receive a real answer ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant Sorry, I was in a hurry and could not complete the question. I have added more information.

Comment: I think this is a known bug on windows. You need to make sure `mainloop` is started before opening a dialog box.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm pretty sure this must be a know bug (though I could not find any hint). Unfortunately I can't start the mainloop in advance (in the above example the askfileopen is some initial question). Do you know of any work around?

Comment: WHy can't you start the mainloop first? You can hide the main window before doing so if you wish.

Comment: @BryanOakley How can I start mainloop() and call askopenfile()? mainloop() will not return until some event (keyboard/mouse) is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen reports of this before, I think it's a known bug on windows. You need to let mainloop start before you open a dialog.

If you want the dialog to appear when the app first starts up you can use `after` or `after_idle` to have it run after `mainloop` starts up.

For example:

```
menu = tk.Tk()
...
def on_startup():
    res = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

menu.after_idle(on_startup)
menu.mainloop()
```

If you don't want any other GUI code to execute until after the dialog, move all your code except for the creation of the root window and call to `mainloop` into `on_startup` or some other function.

For example:

```
def main(filename):
    label = tk.Label(None, text="abc")
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    entry = tk.Entry(None)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)

def on_startup():
    res = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    main(filename)

root = Tk()
root.after_idle(on_startup)
```

Comment: Excellent! The after_idle is the work around. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`askopenfilename`has it's own event loop. The programm stops, until you selected a filename, and continues afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not completed.

Comment: In other words: it does not provide an answer to my question.